# Como marcar e desmarcar uma linha de uma tabela clicando sobre ela?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ao clicar em uma linha de uma tabela, como marcar ela  mudando a cor do fundo da linha, e se clicar novamente desmarcar o fundo, e se clicar em outra linha desmarcar a antiga marcada e marcar a nova.

Como fazer isso usando JavaScript / jQuery?

Comment: Você quer trocar as linhas selecionadas a cada click ou selecionar e desselecionar apenas clicando em casa linha (no segundo caso várias linhas podem estar selecionadas ao mesmo temo, no primeiro não)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pode usar assim:

Para aplicar **na linha toda** pode usar `$('table tr');`

```
var tr = $('table tr:not(:first-child)');  // o :not(:first-child) é util no meu exemplo somente porque usa th
tr.on('click', function () {
    tr.not(this).removeClass('colorir');
    $(this).toggleClass('colorir');
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/5QLLM/)

Deixo **mais uma variante** de código, ligeiramente mais rápido.
Fiz um teste [**(link)**](http://jsperf.com/html-table-toggle) e esta segunda opção é mesmo a mais rápida.

Código:

```
var tr = $('table tr:not(:first-child)');
tr.on('click', function () {
    var self = this;
    tr.each(function(){
        if(this == self) $(this).toggleClass('colorir');
        else $(this).removeClass('colorir');
    })
});
```

[**Exemplo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/8vN9f/)

---

Para aplicar **em cada célula** pode usar `$('table td');`

```
var td = $('table td');          // pôr todas as td em cache
td.on('click', function () {     // agregar um event handler para executar aquando um click
    td.not(this).removeClass('colorir');   // remover a classe em todas as td menos a que recebeu click
    $(this).toggleClass('colorir'); // adicionar/remover a classe àquela que foi clicada
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/p8MNJ/4/)

---

o CSS é o mesmo para as duas opções:

```
.colorir {
    background-color:#fcc;
}
```

Comment: @luiscubal, estava a editar

Comment: Sim, agora está certo. Já agora, se carregar no título, ele des-seleciona todas as linhas. É intencional? Se não for, pode usar o seletor `:not(:first-child)`

Comment: @luiscubal, boa observação! Juntei isso à resposta. Obrigado.

Answer (score 9):

Uma solução componentizada (ou seja, que pode ser encapsulada), é possível usando jQuery e classes css:

```
$("#mytable > tbody > tr").on("click", function (e) {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("ativo");
    $(this).toggleClass("ativo");
});
```

CSS:

```
.ativo {
    background-color: #00F;
    color: white;
}
```

**Selecionando uma tabela específica, e as rows específicas**

O seletor na tabela raiz (i.e. `#mytable`), permite que você coloque outras tabelas na página, sem afetá-las. Assim como o uso do operador `>` para chegar até a row. Isso permite componentizar a solução.

**Porque usar siblings para remover a classe ativo?**

Além disso, remover a classe `ativo` através dos `siblings`, deixa a solução bem encapsulada à tabela desejada. Você poderia possuir subtabelas, dentro da tabela, e ainda assim funcionaria.

O `tbody` no meio serve para selecionar rows apenas do body, nem do footer nem do header.

### [Exemplo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGKrK/2/)

**EDIT**

Pode usar um estilo `user-select: none` para que cliques rápidos na mesma linha não acabem por selecionar o texto.

E também um `cursor: pointer` para indicar que o usuário pode clicar ali.

**EDIT**

Para entrar no mérito da performance, e mantendo o código legível, só digo uma coisa...

## [Exemplo mais performático de todos =)](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGKrK/6/)

<sub>[até que alguém o supere](http://jsperf.com/html-table-toggle-with-cache)</sub>

```
$("#mytable > tbody > tr").on("click", function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // bem... esse não é o lugar mais recomendável para armazenar o cache, ou é?
    this.$siblings = this.$siblings || $this.siblings();
    this.$siblings.removeClass("ativo");
    $this.toggleClass("ativo");
});
```

Comment: +1. É a resposta mais simples, mais completa e mais rápida.
Aqui um fiddle que demonstra a funcionalidade completa usando essa solução: http://jsfiddle.net/ZGKrK/4/

Comment: @SparK, fiz um teste, porque não tinha a certeza: http://jsperf.com/html-table-toggle

Comment: Realmente, esta solução só é boa até 39 cliques por segundo, enquanto as outras soluções são bem melhores e suportam até 115 cliques por segundo. =)

Comment: hmm... no jsperf você inverteu o nome dos testes `not` e `each`, mas deu pra ter uma ideia

Comment: Também fiz um jsperf só pra brincar um pouquinho: http://jsperf.com/html-table-toggle-with-cache

Answer (score 3):

Você terá que no primeiro click adicionar uma classe chamada `active` à `tr` e a partir daí a cada click verificar se a `tr` possui a classe, caso possua você remove, caso não você adiciona.

Exemplo:

```
$("tr").on('click', function () {
    if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }
});
```

E definir o [css](/questions/tagged/css) dessa classe.

Exemplo:

```
tr.active {
    background-color: yelow;
}
```

Você pode ver um exemplo [aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/6xkDT/2/)

Dessa forma cada click irá selecionar ou remover a seleção de uma linha.

Answer (score 3):

Não vi ninguém atender o requisito da pergunta, então segue a minha versão:

```js
$('#codexpl').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('marcada');
    $(this).toggleClass('marcada');
});
```

Ela permite selecionar uma linha por vez e, ao clicar novamente na linha marcada, ela perde a marcação.

#### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RwZ5Q/)

<sup>Nota: o fiddle foi um *fork* baseado na versão do @Sergio</sup>

Comment: Percebi faz pouco isso... hehe

Answer (score 1):

Ou você pode usar uma variável global para armazenar o objeto que está selecionado.

```
$('<tr>').click(function () {
    objMarcado = this;
    $(this).addClass('colorir');
});
```